# How can I change product category columns to 4?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am attempting to change the product category view to 4 columns vs. 3.

As you can see here at: www.tattiniboots.com the Accessory box section is the first and only item in the 2nd row. I would prefer to just have one row with 4 columns

I have dove into the CSS and see that the UL Class is "products columns-3" however, there is no option to actually change that within any of my settings or code

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding this CSS to your theme's CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
.woocommerce ul.products li.last, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.last {
    margin: 0 3.5% 2em 0;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.first, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.first {
    clear: none;
    margin: 0 3.5% 2em 0;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    width: 21%;
}}
```

Or you may also try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-archive-customiser/

Comment: I am currently working on adding some css to maximize the sizing possible. Please view what I am working with now at https://www.tattiniboots.com/shop/

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. I suggest you open a new support request for the new issue.

Comment: I am looking to make each product category image a little larger by reducing the spacing between each block. However anything over 21 will send the final item to row 2

Comment: You can see that there is still more spacing on the right side of the 4 blocks then there is on the left side of the 4 blocks

Comment: Also please view what happens when the screenport is just a little over mobile size; the boxes are spaced into every corner

Comment: I modified my code so that it only applies to desktop and it doesn't affect mobile.

Comment: In regards to spacing on desktop. You can reduce the values of 3.5% in that code and increase the value of 21%.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use in your theme's function.php:

```
add_filter( 'storefront_loop_columns', function() { return 4; } ); //change shop colunns//
```

and in your theme css:

```
.site-main ul.products li.product {
    width: 25%;
    margin-right:4%;
}
```

Comment: I have added that filter to my functions.php as well as the css. Please check now, as nothing has changed

Comment: it is better to provide some codes nad attach what you tried.
if nothing changes you have to change it in your themes setting inside wp-admin in woocommerce section if it has